# Getting the size of a micro SD card via C++

Tags: c++, linux, eclipse, ubuntu, g++

I am looking for some function that will return the total capacity of a micro SD card mounted to /dev/sdb. I do not care so much about free space I care about total capacity of the drive. I need a reliable and accurate function. If there is none in existence how would I go about creating one?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean raw device capacity or file system capacity? The FS capacity will be less than the total size of the underlying device.

Comment: Due to the title I'm so tempted to say [`const char* const getMicroSDSize() { return "15 mm × 11 mm × 1.0 mm"; }`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Digital#Physical_size)

Comment: @sehe: Make that 0.7mm instead 1.0 :-)

Comment: @ott--: feel free to _correct_ (?) the wikipedia entry I linked to...

Comment: @sehe: I'll try to add that. This german page (http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/MicroSD) may be incomplete too, but it says 0.7 - and the Micro-SD in my fingers is for sure less than 1.0mmm - I'll report later.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

strace for `blockdev` tells me you could use:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <linux/fs.h>

int main()
{
    unsigned long long size;
    int fd = open("/dev/sdx", O_RDONLY);
    ioctl(fd, BLKGETSIZE64, &size);

    std::cout << size << std::endl;
    std::cout << (size>>20) << std::endl; // MiBytes
}
```

(replace sdx by device node name)

**Note** prefer using `uint64_t` if your compiler supports it already (include `<cstdint>`)

Answer (score 1):

You can just read a special file in the `/sys/` directory:

```
/sys/block/sdb/sdb1/size
```

It returns the size in bytes.

Comment: 'size' is returned in blocks, to get actual size you should multiply this value by the block size (usually 512 bytes).