# How to get Android SD card size?

Tags: java, android, storage

First, I'd like to start by saying, yes I have read and tried just about every single question on this topic posted to SO, so please do not link me to other answers. For example, I have tried something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16835201/3150458), but it returns the same as internal storage. I have about 12GB internal storage and 4GB SD card storage, but no matter what method I use, I always get the exact same number for the SD space as I do for internal space. Are there any other methods to obtaining SD card space?

Comment: Have you tried this?
http://www.41post.com/4374/programming/android-obtaining-sd-card-memory-information

Comment: This might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7829300/getting-the-size-of-a-micro-sd-card-via-c (in C/C++, but it'd be something similar for Java)

Comment: @PandaConda Thanks, I tried that implementation in Java, but a value of 0 was returned.

Comment: If y'all are curious, I've answered with some code I wrote below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I ended up writing a bit of code that uses the file `/etc/vold.fstab` to get all the **actual** external storage devices. On my TF101 with the docking station attached and populated with storage devices, this will correctly return the path to the microSD, SD, and usb drives.

```
private ArrayList<String> extStorageLoc(){
        String[] toSearch = readFile("/etc/vold.fstab").split(" ");
        ArrayList<String> out = new ArrayList<String>();
        for(int i = 0; i < toSearch.length; i++){
            if(toSearch[i].contains("dev_mount")){
                if(new File(toSearch[i+2]).exists()){
                    out.add(toSearch[i+2]);
                }
            }
        }
        return out;
}
```